# How to find the sum of Columns in table and insert the sum as New Row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got this results after executing some sort of query

[image]which has these rows:

I want to calculate the Total Marks as (12/38 + 14/23 + ....) for each students in the given result and insert that into new row 
as

StudentName ,StudentId ,term, "**Total**"  as Subject, "**Calculated TotalMarks**" as Marks, Class, Dicision,id, **null** as DivisionSubject_SubjectProirity

Is thr any way to do it....
Plz let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query.

First `select` all values into **temp table**

```
select 
       StudentName,
       StudentId,
       term,
       cast(sum(convert(int,substring(Marks,1,CHARINDEX('/',Marks,1)-1))) as varchar) As 'Subject',
       cast(sum(convert(int,substring(Marks,CHARINDEX('/',Marks,1)+1,len(Marks)))) as varchar) As Marks,
       class,
       division,
       id
into #t
from tablename
group by StudentName,StudentId,term,class,division,id
```

Now use the **Bulk Insert**

```
insert into table_insert
(
StudentName
,StudentId
,term
,[Subject]
,Marks
,class
,division
,id
,DivisionSubject_SubjectPriority
)
select 
StudentName
,StudentId
,term
,[Subject]
,Marks
,class
,division
,id
,NULL
from #t
```

Comment: @Anoop Mohan Have to tried it and did it help you to find the answer.

Comment: @Luv- Thanks Luv.I got what i needed from Your answer...Sorry for the delay